# Criterion for a group $G$ to be abelian using $Inn(G)$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $(G, *)$ be a group. Let $\mathcal S(G)=\{f:G\to G\space|f\space is\space bijective\}$ be the symmetric group and $Inn(G)=\{\kappa_{a}\space|\space a\in G\}$ the inner automorphisms. Now I want to show:

> $G$ is abelian $\Leftrightarrow$ $Inn(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathcal S(G)$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The linked answer is *only* one direction at most.

Comment: @Joanpemo yes i also think so, i have seen this  question and it's answers

Comment: Maybe I should have link this question, I'm sorry for this missunderstanding. However I would be very thankfull if somebody can help me.

Comment: Unfortunately chances are mods won't re-open the question. Sometimes things can be pretty non-flexible in this site and one can't know what's going on. Weird.

Comment: Should i ask a new question ?

Comment: You can try...but maybe some people will then link it to this. Pretty absurd if you aske me, but in the very short time I've been around I'[ve seen that several times. It seems to be some kind of tabu or religious rule in this site about repeated questions...I'd try, though.

Comment: @joan Reasking seems like terrible advice. And the missing direction is completely trivial.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. I just can't see it neither as terrible nor even as bad or even non-nice, in particular when a linked question is *not* the same as the asked question. That the missing direction is trivial is, in my opinion, irrelevant here. If the one missing was the tough one also the question, most probably, would have been closed. I've seen examples of this. Even in cases when the linked question is very odd and it is safely forgotten, questions have been closed. I just can't understand what so terrible in re-asking...